# SOAP API RetrieveRequest for specific Business Unit

Tags: api, soap-api, marketing-cloud

I am trying to pull information about various sends from the API in an automated fashion into a Ruby on Rails app.

I can successfully run the call and parse the results for the entire account (including all business units) using this hash as my soap body:

```
{
  'tns:RetrieveRequest' => {
    'ObjectType' => 'Send',
    'Properties' => ['Additional', 'Duplicates', 'ExistingUndeliverables', 'ExistingUnsubscribes', 'ForwardedEmails', 'HardBounces', 'InvalidAddresses', 'MissingAddresses', 'NumberDelivered', 'NumberErrored', 'NumberExcluded', 'NumberSent', 'NumberTargeted', 'OtherBounces', 'SendDate', 'SendLimit', 'SentDate', 'SoftBounces', 'UniqueClicks', 'UniqueOpens', 'Unsubscribes','EmailName', 'Additional', 'ID','PartnerKey', 'PreviewURL'],
    'QueryAllAccounts' => true,
    :attributes! =>
    {
      'Filter' => {"xsi:type" => "tns:SimpleFilterPart"}
    },
    'Filter' =>
    {
      'Property' => 'SendDate',
      'SimpleOperator' => 'between',
      'DateValue' => ['2014-02-05', '2014-02-13']
    }
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't give me a good way to tie any of the sends back to specific business units (which correspond to our own internal customers). I'm looking for a way to either pull back business unit information as part of this call, or to run this call for only one business unit at a time.

I've been trying things like this for my soap body but to no avail:

```
{
  'tns:RetrieveRequest' => {
    'ObjectType' => 'Send',
    'Properties' => ['Additional', 'Duplicates', 'ExistingUndeliverables', 'ExistingUnsubscribes', 'ForwardedEmails', 'HardBounces', 'InvalidAddresses', 'MissingAddresses', 'NumberDelivered', 'NumberErrored', 'NumberExcluded', 'NumberSent', 'NumberTargeted', 'OtherBounces', 'SendDate', 'SendLimit', 'SentDate', 'SoftBounces', 'UniqueClicks', 'UniqueOpens', 'Unsubscribes','EmailName', 'Additional', 'ID','PartnerKey', 'PreviewURL'],
    'QueryAllAccounts' => true,
    'PartnerProperties' => 
    {
      'Name' => 'ClientID',
      'Value' => '0123456'
    },
    :attributes! =>
    {
      'Filter' => {"xsi:type" => "tns:SimpleFilterPart"}
    },
    'Filter' =>
    {
      'Property' => 'SendDate',
      'SimpleOperator' => 'between',
      'DateValue' => ['2014-02-05', '2014-02-13']
    }
  }
}
```

Can you provide me with the appropriate formatting of a call that can meet my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have the request return the ID for the Business Unit that the Send is related to by including `Client.ID` in the `Properties` array being passed.

It is also possible to specify a specific business unit for the retrieve by specifying the `RetrieveRequest > ClientIDs > ID` property and setting `QueryAllAccounts` to True.  Example SOAP would look like:

```xml
<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <RetrieveRequest>
        <ClientIDs>
            <ID>100000</ID>
        </ClientIDs>
        <ObjectType>Send</ObjectType>
        <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
        <Properties>ID</Properties>
        <Properties>SendDate</Properties>
        <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
    </RetrieveRequest>
</RetrieveRequestMsg>
```